# How to delete iPhone delete data from plist file

Tags: ios, plist

I have a plist file in my document directory.

I need to delete some key with their value programatically.

Comment: So, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would read in the plist in

get the URL of the plist and read it in

```
 NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
```

then break it down into objects. plist are just a hierarchy of different NSObjects usually the root is an Array or a dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *plistData = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&error];
```

Modify the dictionary then re-write it to the documents folder.